# can't update iPhone 6S to public beta 9.1

Tags: iphone, ios, beta-seed-program

I have a new iPhone 6S and need to upgrade it to the public beta for 9.1 in order to restore my back up from my old iPhone

I have installed the profile on the device as per their instructions then restarted but every time I go to settings > general > software update I get this error:

> An error occurred while checking for a software update, cancel or try again

Is their another way to install the beta?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the profile, restarting, then reinstalling the profile?

Comment: Several times and still no joy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about an old beta with no useful answers and is now attacking answers which don't really help

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial: http://www.imore.com/how-download-ios-93-public-beta

Your question being old, I'm guessing you might be interested in iOS 10 now, which you can obtain through a) a paid Developer account, b) invite to Apple's Public Betas, which should be coming soon, or c) an Apple Seed invitation, which you can't ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it via iTunes.

Link for firmware files.

Choose your file with caution...

http://www.ios9cydia.com/download-ios-9

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -